# Перейти по первой ссылке выдачи Yandex и проверить ее на cоответствие

Tags: python, selenium

Как перейти по первой ссылке в Яндексе и проверить ее на соответствие при помощи Selenium(Python)?

1. Вводится запрос (допустим samsung) и производится, с этим я разобрался

   ```
   driver.get("http://www.yandex.ru") 
   elem = driver.find_element_by_id("text")
   elem.send_keys("samsung")
   ```
2. Необходимо проверить то что первая ссылка ведет на https://www.samsung.com/  вот тут у меня возникла проблема, я не знаю каким образом "выцепить" именно первую ссылку в яндексе, ибо они однозначно не помечены уникальным id или классом. 
   Также не могу понять каким образом сравнивать ссылки, ибо в href отображается поисковая ссылка яндекса, а не на конкретный сайт.

Comment: Как выцепить и проверить: сделайте поиск через xpath/css-селектор, например через селектор: `.main__content li.serp-item > div.organic a.link`. Так получите элемент тега `a`, у него вытаскиваете атрибут `href` и сравниваете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по xpath, например:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='suggest2-item__text suggest2-item__text_type_url']").text #выдаёт u'www.samsung.com/ru/home/'
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='suggest2-item__text suggest2-item__text_type_url']"}

Comment: @АлександрЛожковой У меня работает...
Какой браузер и драйвер?

Comment: Chromedriver, браузер соответственно тоже Chrome 67.0.3396.99 64bit

Comment: А если воткнуть sleep?
У меня браузер 68.x...